# Mesh created with connected vertices don't create correct mesh

Tags: mesh

[image: Selected faces]
I started with a simple plane mesh and then continued working with by creating new vertices by selecting the edges and then subdivide them. Then I connected two vertices with `F` button to create a new mesh and continued working like this, but it seems there are problems in model, because all visibile meshes are not real meshes and I can't select them! The normals show those who are correct.

I searched for info about this and found that a manifold thing could be the problem, but I'm not sure how to make this model correct again?

To create meshes with new vertices on edges and also create them with `CTRL` button and a mouse click and then connect them with another edge or vertex, is this not a recomended way of working or how can I avoid getting this problem in the future?

Preciate some help to be able to continue with my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; I would highly advise against modeling in this way. It would be much better to use extrude operations (**E** key) to create your mesh.

If you wish to continue with your current mesh, two ways I would recommend trying to fix it is by first removing any doubles (**Spacebar** > Search "**Remove Doubles**"), and then recalculating the normals in the **3D View Tools** menu:

[image]

If you can attach a Blend file, I could take a look at your mesh and see what else may be able to be fixed, but I would honestly recommend starting from scratch on this one and modeling with better practices.

**EDIT:**

Here is an example of how you might start building a mesh with extrusion and loop tools, although for a car, I would highly recommend using **Background Images** of your car and start working your way around that. Here is an excellent resource to get you started in that workflow: http://darkscarab.com/view/43

[image: Example modeling]

Comment: I have tried to remove doubles, but it's not removing any and recalculate normals don't work, so I guess I have to start over with a new model. I have used E to extrude some of the edges in the model, but is this also bad to select edges and subdivide them to create new vertices and then connect them with F? This seems to be a nice option when you create a body of a car and things like that? Is it better to use K for the knife and create new edges then? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Or the CTRL + R tool to create new edges/meshes?

Comment: @3D-kreativ I would not subdivide edges when creating a car, you don't want N-Gons in a smooth, organic mesh like a car body. Try to use loops (**Ctrl + R**) when you need new edges, and try to avoid the knife tool if possible. If it perfectly acceptable to use **F** to join and make faces, but only if you are creating quads.

Comment: @3D-kreativ I've update my original post with more information regarding modeling techniques, and a link to a tutorial on modeling a car.

Comment: After you extrude a vertex, what is your next step to create a mesh?

Comment: @3D-kreativ I would avoid extruding individual vertices whenever possible, but if you must you should create a face between that vertex and 3 other points to form a quad (as seen in my GIF above).